# How to load image by 'image name' from Images.Media

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**How to load image by 'image name' from Images.Media "Images.Media"?** 
I have to load and display image "12343333322434.jpg"

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {  
        string imageName = "12343333322434.jpg"; 
        Bitmap bitmap = getImageByImageName(imageName);
        viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);    
    }

  public Bitmap getImageByImageName(String fileName)
  {
              // I am looking the implementation of this function
  }
```

I am using Android studio 1.3.2

Comment: do you have any idea what your problem is (besides the fact that you are using android studio which is not relevant here)?

Comment: Hi pskink, I have updated the question. I am looking for the implementation of function "getImageByImageName"

Comment: see `MediaStore.Images.Media#getBitmap(ContentResolver cr, Uri url)`